# How to skip rendering empty/blank lines from exploded textarea

Tags: php

I am trying to not render blank/empty lines that are entered within a textarea. I'm using the below code to explode each line and wrap it in an < li > tag. In the screenshot, you can see that empty lines are being rendered.

[image: See the empty lines]

```
<?php
    $instruction_textarea = get_field('instructions_textarea');
    $lines = explode("\n", $instruction_textarea); 
        if ( !empty($lines) ) {
            echo '<ol itemprop="recipeInstructions">';
            foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
            echo '<li>'. trim( $line ) .'</li>';
            }
            echo '</ol>';
        }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure the empty lines *are* empty, then call `array_filter()` without a callback to remove all empty lines:

```
$lines = array_map( 'trim', $lines );
$lines = array_filter( $lines );
```

Comment: Finally got around to testing this, thanks. There seems to be no effect though, the empty lines are still rendering.

Comment: Looks like this code is actually good, but I've got something conflicting with my setup in Wordpress. So thank you for your help, I just need to figure this out on my end.